# Maven - How can I use a dependency on compile classpath only?

Tags: java, maven, scope, dependencies, option-type

Here is a dependency in pom.xml from Project B

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
       ...
     </dependencies>
```

I want to include Project B as a dependency of Project A. However I want to have lombok as a dependency of Project A with same scope (ie I want lombok to be on the compilation classpath of Project A only).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided dependencies are not transitive. So you need to define that dependency in Project A as well.

Check the scope and dependency [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-transitive)